# How to properly handle Fin n and Integer when computing dates?

Tags: date, dependent-type, idris

In my journey exploring Idris, I am trying to write a small dates-handling module in an "idiomatic" way. Here is what I have so far.

First I have some basic types to represent days, months and years:

```
module Date 

import Data.Fin

Day : Type
Day = Fin 32

data Month : Type where
  January    : Month
  February   : Month
  .... 

toNat : Month -> Nat
toNat January    = 1
toNat February   = 2
... 

data Year : Type where
  Y : Integer -> Year

record Date where
  constructor MkDate
  day   : Day
  month : Month 
  year  : Year
```

I would like to implement a function `addDays` to add some number of days to a `Date`. To this end I defined the following auxiliary functions:

```
isLeapYear : Year -> Bool
isLeapYear (Y y) = 
  (((y `mod` 4) == 0) && ((y `mod` 100) /= 0)) || ((y `mod` 400) == 0) 

daysInMonth : Month -> Year -> Day
daysInMonth January _      = 31
daysInMonth February year  = if isLeapYear year then 29 else 28
daysInMonth March _        = 31
...
```

And finally try to define `addDays` as :

```
addDays : Date -> Integer -> Date
addDays (MkDate d m y) days =
  let maxDays = daysInMonth m y
      shiftedDays = finToInteger d + days
  in case integerToFin shiftedDays (finToNat maxDays) of  
          Nothing => ?hole_1
          Just x  => MkDate x m y
```

I am stuck with the very basic case where the added number of days fit in the current month's duration. Here is the output of compiler:

When checking right hand side of Date.case block in addDays at Date.idr:92:11 with expected type
             Date

```
 When checking argument day to constructor Date.MkDate:
         Type mismatch between
                 Fin (finToNat maxDays) (Type of x)
         and
                 Day (Expected type)

         Specifically:
                 Type mismatch between
                         finToNat maxDays
                 and
                         32
```

This is puzzling because the type of `maxDays` should be obviously `Day` which is simply `Fin 32`.

I suspect this might be related to non-totality of `daysInMonth` which stems from non-totality of `isLeapYear` which itself comes from non-totality of `mod` for `Integer` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not so trivial because *Idris* requires proofs from you on every step especially if you're using dependent types. All basic ideas are already written in this question:

[Is there a way to define a consistent date in a dependent type language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257465/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-consistent-date-in-a-dependent-type-language)

I'll comment your implementation and translate code in answer (it's probably *Agda*) to *Idris*. Also I made few adjustments to make your code total.

First, `Month` can be written a little bit simpler:

```
data Month = January
           | February
           | March
```

I'm not going to write all 12 month, it's just an example.

Second, `Year` type should store `Nat` instead of `Integer` because most functions that work with `Integer` aren't total. This is better:

```
data Year : Type where
    Y : Nat -> Year
```

It helps to make `isLeapYear` check total:

```
isLeapYear : Year -> Bool
isLeapYear (Y y) = check4 && check100 || check400
  where
    check4 : Bool
    check4 = modNatNZ y 4 SIsNotZ == 0

    check100 : Bool
    check100 = modNatNZ y 100 SIsNotZ /= 0

    check400 : Bool
    check400 = modNatNZ y 400 SIsNotZ == 0
```

Next, it's not good to make `Day` as a `Fin 32`. Better to specify day's number for each month specifically.

```
daysInMonth : Month -> Year -> Nat
daysInMonth January  _    = 31
daysInMonth February year = if isLeapYear year then 29 else 28
daysInMonth March    _    = 31

Day : Month -> Year -> Type
Day m y = Fin (daysInMonth m y)
```

And you should adjust a little your `Date` record:

```
record Date where
    constructor MkDate
    year  : Year
    month : Month
    day   : Day month year
```

Well, now about `addDays`. This function is actually very complex when you're working with dependent types. As you correctly noticed, you have several cases. For example: sum fits in the current month, sum goes to next month, sum skips several months, sum goes to year. And each such case need proof. If you want to ensure that sum fits in current month, you should provide a proof of that fact.

Before I move to code I want to warn you that writing even non-typed versions of date library is [increadibly hard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY). Moreover, I suppose nobody haven't still tried to implement full-featured version in some language with dependent types. So my solution may be far from the best. But at least should give you some ideas about what you're doing wrong.

Then you can start with writing some function like this:

```
daysMax : (d: Date) -> Nat
daysMax (MkDate y m _) = daysInMonth m y

addDaysSameMonth : (d : Date)
                -> (n : Nat)
                -> Prelude.Nat.LT (finToNat (day d) + n) (daysMax d)
                -> Date
addDaysSameMonth d n x = ?addDaysSameMonth_rhs
```

Well, numeric operations with `Fin` are very limited according to current state of [`Data.Fin` module](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/7bd33c23558ac35be0c4f65ca90654eb1a433cbe/libs/base/Data/Fin.idr). So you may have hard times even adding two `Nat`s and converting them to `Fin` using given proof. Again, writing such stuff is harder than it seems :)

Here is the full sketch of code: http://lpaste.net/3314444314070745088

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights, very helpful as usual! I actually know working with dates *and* time is extremely hard and fraught with great perils. I have been bitten enough by timezones issues to learn the lesson. My ambition was more modest and working on dates came up as a yak-shaving exercise triggered by another problem I was working on. My ambitions are not to build a full-blown date library (not yet), only to have a workable and interesting `Date` type

Comment: Thank you too for the link to other SO question which lead me to this: https://forge.ocamlcore.org/scm/viewvc.php/trunk/calendarFAQ-2.6.txt?view=markup&root=calendar Definitely a great read!